# Get 3rd ranked record or the oldest one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table let's say `emp_sal` and I want to find out the **3rd record** of the employee based on `change_date` in **descending order**.

But the issue is for few employees, there are less than three records and for such an employees I need 2nd(if two rows are there in table for that employee) or 1st(if only one record is there in table for that employee) record.

**emp_sal table with data:**

| empid | change_date | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 1400 |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | 1450 |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | 1500 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 | 2500 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | 2400 |
| 2 | 2023-12-15 | 2200 |
| 3 | 2023-05-01 | 500 |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 | 640 |
| 4 | 2023-10-01 | 3000 |

I tried using the `ROW_NUMBER` but unable to get the records with less than 3 records.

```
select * from 
(select e.*, row_number() over (partition by empid order by change_date desc) as rn
  from emp_sal e)
where rn = 3; -- what other condition is needed here, I am not sure
```

**Expected output:**

| empid | change_date | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 1400 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 | 2500 |
| 3 | 2023-05-01 | 500 |
| 4 | 2023-10-01 | 3000 |

Help will be appreciated a lot. Let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `count(*) over (partition by empid) cnt` to the inner query, you can set your filter to `where rn = least(3, cnt)`.

```
select s.empid, s.change_date, s.salary
from (
    select
        e.*,
        row_number() over (partition by e.empid order by e.change_date desc) as rn,
        count(*) over (partition by e.empid) as cnt
    from emp_sal e
) s
where s.rn = least(3, s.cnt)
order by s.empid;
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iGZjPIFb).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with emp_sal (empid, change_date, salary) as
  2    (select 1, date '2023-01-01', 1000 from dual union all select
  3     1, date '2023-02-01', 1400 from dual union all select
  4     1, date '2023-03-01', 1450 from dual union all select
  5     1, date '2023-04-01', 1500 from dual union all select
  6     --
  7     2, date '2023-11-01', 2500 from dual union all select
  8     2, date '2023-12-01', 2400 from dual union all select
  9     2, date '2023-12-15', 2200 from dual union all select
 10     --
 11     3, date '2023-05-01',  500 from dual union all select
 12     3, date '2023-06-01',  640 from dual union all select
 13     --
 14     4, date '2023-10-01', 3000 from dual
 15    ),
```

Query: `temp` CTE is just as your subquery:

```
 16  temp as
 17    (select empid, change_date, salary,
 18       row_number() over (partition by empid order by change_date desc) rn
 19     from emp_sal
 20    )
 21  select *
 22  from temp a
```

This is what returns data you need:

```
 23  where a.rn = (select max(b.rn) from temp b
 24                where b.empid = a.empid
 25                  and b.rn <= 3
 26               )
 27  order by a.empid;

     EMPID CHANGE_DAT     SALARY         RN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2023-02-01       1400          3
         2 2023-11-01       2500          3
         3 2023-05-01        500          2
         4 2023-10-01       3000          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..)` analytic function in order to get the greatest ***rn*** per each ***empid*** such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT empid, 
       MAX(change_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY empid, rn DESC) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS change_date,
            MAX(salary) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY empid, rn DESC) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS salary  
  FROM
  ( SELECT e.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY change_date DESC) AS rn
      FROM emp_sal e )
 WHERE rn <= 3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZYyZrE_V)</kbd>

or you might use `ROW_NUMBER()` function twice along with FETCH clause including `WITH TIES` option as

```
SELECT empid, change_date, salary
  FROM
  (
   SELECT e.*, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY change_date DESC) AS rn
     FROM emp_sal e
  ) e1
 WHERE rn <= 3
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY rn DESC) 
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/u_YN3pKh)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` twice, first to filter the latest 3 rows for each `empid` and second to get the earliest of those rows:

```sql
SELECT empid,
       change_date,
       salary
FROM   (
  SELECT empid,
         change_date,
         salary,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY change_date ASC) AS rn2
  FROM   (
    SELECT empid,
           change_date,
           salary,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY change_date DESC) AS rn1
    FROM   emp_sal
  )
  WHERE  rn1 <= 3
)
WHERE  rn2 = 1
ORDER BY empid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp_sal (empid, change_date, salary) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-01-01', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-01', 1400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-03-01', 1450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-04-01', 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-11-01', 2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-12-01', 2400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-12-15', 2200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-05-01',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-06-01',  640 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2023-10-01', 3000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMPID | CHANGE_DATE | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 1400 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 2500 |
| 3 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 500 |
| 4 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 3000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jUuKqJXf)